App drawer is not closed in flutter webview
I have a Flutter project where I utilize flutter_inappwebview to display a website within a webview. When I run the website in Flutter web using Chrome browser, the website launches properly. However, when I try to close the drawer by clicking outside of it, the drawer does not close as expected. Instead, the content within the webview gets selected or clicked. My goal is to ensure that the drawer closes when it's open, allowing normal interaction with the webview otherwise. How can I achieve this functionality?
I've experimented with various solutions such as PointerInspector and GestureDetector, but none have effectively resolved the issue.
expectation
I expect the drawer to close when clicking outside it, allowing normal interaction with the webview content.
